# Angularjs static number filter with custom delimiter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to change delimiter in Angularjs number filter from comma to something custom?

Now `{{ price | number }}` returns `1,000.00`.
And I need to have it like `1 000.00`.

How exactly do I need to rewrite built-in angular filter?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't have to mess with Angular source or change locale to other. You don't even need to write custom filter for this. just change `NUMBER_FORMATS.GROUP_SEP` of the $locale service to whatever you need:

```
$locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.GROUP_SEP = ' ';
$scope.price = 100000;
```

But it's better to do it in run block, rather then in controller.

```js
angular.module('demo', []).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $locale) {
    $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.GROUP_SEP = ' ';
    $scope.price = 100000;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    {{ price | number }}    
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure in run block? Not in config one?

Comment: Anyway, it works. I guess, the best answer. Thanks dude.

Comment: Because $localeProvider doesn't expose those properties, so you can't reset it so easily in config block. Better to say: because ngLocale module creates `$locale` which is a value (not provider or constant), so it's not accessible in config block.