# $filter number without comma value return

Tags: angularjs

Hi below line of code returning with '1,000.23' value, but I need like '1000.23'.
Here I don't want comma separator value like 1,000.23

```
$filter('number')(1000.23456, 2); // return 1,000.23 but I need this as 1000.23
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33561186/how-can-i-use-numbers-with-angular-js-without-comma-and-dot

Comment: Or see this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31809208/angularjs-static-number-filter-with-custom-delimiter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution without angular $filter:

```js
var number =  '1,000.23';
number = (num => num.split(',').join(''))(number);
console.log(number);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this filter, to your app

```
angular.module('app').filter('fix2', function ($filter) {
    return function (number, pre) {
        return number.toFixed(pre);
    };
});
```

In Controller

```
$filter('fix2')(1000.23456, 2);
```

In view

```
<div>{{ '1000.23456' | fix2 : 2 }}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another version of Faly's answer:

```js
var number =  '1,000.23';
number = number.split(',').join('');
console.log(number);
```